# electron.js and node.js server deploy problem

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I want to open a web page on localhost when the button is clicked and I want to run the node app command. I can easily run this process with electron.js. everything is fine, but when I deploy the application, my server does not start on the web page that opens when I click the button and the page cannot be displayed.

package.json :

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dist": "electron-builder -w --ia32 --x64",
  "postinstall": "electron-rebuild -f -w express socket.io ejs string-hex serialport"
},
"dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^3.1.5",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "serialport": "^12.0.0",
  "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
  "string-hex": "^1.0.0"
},
"build": {
  "appId": "com.sailteknoloji.noxtester",
  "productName": "Nox Tester",
  "asar":"false",
  "win": {
    "target":"msi",
    "icon": "/icon/nox-tester-icon-256.ico"
  }
},
"devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^27.0.2",
  "spectron": "^19.0.0",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
  "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.9"
}
```

main.js

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const shell = electron.shell;
const ipcMain = electron.ipcMain;
const { exec } = require('child_process');
//const server = require('./app.js');
const nodePath = require('path');

app.on('ready', () => {
let mainWindow;
function createWindow() {
    const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 610,
        height: 450,
        transparent: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
          }
    }); 


    mainWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'webpage.html'))
    .then(() => { mainWindow.show(); })

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}



    //server.startServer();
    createWindow();
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});



ipcMain.on('open-webpage', (event, arg) => {
  shell.openExternal('http://localhost:8000');
  
  const child = exec('node app.js', {
    // Bu komutu çalıştırmak istediğiniz dizini buraya yazın
    cwd: __dirname
  });

  child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });

  child.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
});
```